# Why did this character kill Sparky?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, wandavision

In the end of episode 7 of *WandaVision*, Agatha says the line: "And I killed Sparky too!", revealing that she was the one that killed him in episode 5. Why did she do that? How would that help her in her goal?

Comment: I'll get you, my pretty and your little dog too!

Comment: To show that she's evil [insert TV Tropes link here]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agatha’s initial motivations are simply to find out how Wanda created the hex, it’s a thing created from immense power. She’s aware of the power involved after being around for so long, so is curious to know how. If Wanda knows she can teach her, she’ll be able to learn it herself and become even more powerful.

> **Agatha:** Listen, I need you... Hey, Wanda, I need you to tell me how you did this.
>
> **Wanda:** I didn’t do anything. I’m not...
>
> <sub>*WandaVision*, Season 1 Episode 8, “Previously On...”</sub>

Of course instead of having Wanda teach her she could also just absorb her magic. However, I don’t believe this is the motivation behind killing Sparky. She may have been drawn initially to absorb the magic but not when she saw the extent of it.

She kills Sparky to try and trigger the emotion in Wanda to reveal herself. She likely suspects emotion played a part in what is happening here, considering what she’s seen, so wanted to trigger it. She does this in episode 8 as well by walking Wanda through her journey to trigger the emotion again and get the answer.

Comment: Of course it could just be that she’s eeeeEEEeevil!

Comment: I think she thought Wanda would bring the dog back - indeed revealing her power.